# Visual Studio extension code completion- multiple file data

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm looking to create code completion for a custom language in Visual Studio. I already have code for some simpler editor interaction, like syntax highlighting and brace matching. Now I want to move to code completion. But I've run into a slight problem- data sources.

Like in a language such as C#, I implicitly share code between more than one file. This implies that, in order to code complete one file, I need to know the contents of the other files. More specifically, whilst I could simply iterate through the project and project items and crack open the files, this is a suboptimal solution. For example, I wouldn't be able to code complete unsaved changes the user has made. For another, I already did a lot of processing work lexing or parsing the contents to fill the user's request for syntax highlighting and whatnot, and I have no desire to duplicate that work.

How can I access the contents of the other files in the project, and obtain their ITextBuffers so I can re-use the work I already did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `ITextBuffer` provided for files which exist on disk but are not currently open in Visual Studio.  It is possible to create an instance of `ITextBuffer` for any arbitrary file by using `ITextDocumentFactoryService::CreateAndLoadDocument`.  This takes a string and will give back an `ITextDocument` instance from which you can access an `ITextBuffer`.

In order to find the existing `ITextBuffer` for files that are currently open you can do the following

- `IVsRunningDocumentTable::FindDocument`  This takes a file path and returns a cookie representing that file if it is currently open ([Example](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/blob/master/Src/VsVimShared/Implementation/Misc/VsAdapter.cs#L250))
- `IVsRunningDocumentTable::GetDocumentInfo` This takes a cookie and returns back an `IVsTextLines` instance ([Example](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/blob/master/Src/VsVimShared/Implementation/Misc/VsAdapter.cs#L224))
- `IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService::GetDataBuffer` takes an `IVsTextLines` and gives back an `ITextBuffer` ([Example](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/blob/master/Src/VsVimShared/Implementation/Misc/VsAdapter.cs#L224))

Comment: If I create my own TextBuffer for files which aren't open, will the IDE re-use them if the user tries to open them?

Comment: Also, I'm looking at the documentation for IVsRunningDocumentTable and the interface isn't that similar. For example, I can only get an IVsHierarchy from GetDocumentInfo.

Comment: @DeadMG i added links to sample code which shows you how to get the `IVsTextLine` instance from `GetDocumentInfo`.  I was typing on the fly and forgot that it is stored as `object` on that structure not `IVsTextLines` and requires some casting magic.

Comment: @DeadMG no to your first question.  if you call into `CreateAndLoadDocument` VS will not hook up that existing `ITextBuffer` if it ever opens that file in the future.  You will have to drop it and simple reload it.  Yeah it's no fun to have to do this.  :(

Comment: Ah, actually, a good part of the problem seems to be that you meant [RunningDocumentTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.runningdocumenttable_members(v=vs.90).aspx) as opposed to [IVsRunningDocumentTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsrunningdocumenttable_members(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: @DeadMG doh! `RunningDocumentTable` is a thin layer over `IVsRunningDocumentTable` and I forget that I often use it instead of the raw interface

Comment: I'm actually struggling with this method right now. It seems that (I have updated to VS2013) the GetDataBuffer() method always returns a new `ITextBuffer`. I have a parse tree cache thingy I attached to the buffer with `buffer.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty`, but the `Create` part is called every time for the ITextBuffers I get back, making the extension unusably slow as it re-parses every file every time.

Comment: Ah, I merely forgot your adage about the CreateAndLoadDocument not being cached as part of the RDT. My mistake. I simply introduced my own internal cache for loaded files and this appears to function just fine.

Comment: @Puppy Is your final version of this by any chance open source?

Comment: @OmerRaviv: It is... somewhere. Not 100% sure where atm.